# How to turn remote ExtJS package to local?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I use a third-party package in my application. It's a package with an icon font. After I installed it, it was placed by sencha cmd into **/packages/remote** directory.

I want that this package would be placed into **/packages/local**.

Is it sufficient just to copy the content of package from **remote** to **local** directory, or there are some more actions needed?
What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy it to **/packages/local** directory and it should work as usual. For additional information, if needed, require it in the **requires** array of  **app.json** and do a development build.